# password protection acting differently in different browsers (with htaccess)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, authentication, password-protection

Right, here's the thing: I'm trying to password protect some files in a specific folder. All files are images so I decided to "tag" the ones I want to protect by adding "p_" (for "private") at the beginning of each file. Here's the htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "^[pP]_.*">
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password required"
Require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

The result, on this side, differs from one browser to another:

- Firefox: asks for password once and works fine
- Chrome (latest version): prompt authentication box again and again when valid psw is entered
- IE8: asks for password every time it comes across a "tagged" file

You guys can test: http://pierre-albiero.com/ip/es/top/imagenes login:test

Am I missing a line in htaccess or got the regex wrong? 
Do you have the same result on your side?

Comment: For me, Chrome (version 15) asks password once and works fine after that.

Comment: Really? Mine is v16.0.912.75m, could you update yours and fill me in?
Did you try on other browsers, is it ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is indeed largely dependent on the browser. The webserver uses a HTTP header flag to indicate that the accessed content is protected. The browser can then submit a login and password to authenticate with the webserver.

But as HTTP is stateless (as soon the site is transmitted, the client closes the connection and the webserver doesn't recognize the client anymore) the browser has to send the authentication information every time it wants to download the specific data.

So to make it comfortable for the user, many browsers cache the authentication information for the website, so that you don't have to enter it for every single item again and again. When chrome asks repeatedly there may be a setting that prevents caching of those passwords, or it is a bug in your version of chrome.

(Wikipedia has a nice example of what happens in the communication: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication )

I tested it here also with Opera. When I entered a password I could access the images repeatedly without entering the password again. Then I deleted the cache and reloaded the website -> Opera asks for the password again.

Comment: I see.
Is there any way I can force the HTTP request to last a bit, say 30 seconds or is it just useless?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't force caching of the password for the client. You may have to look at your browser options. I tested it with my Chrome (16.0.912.75 m) again and it also saves login and password. So there may be some issues with your local configuration.

Comment: Mmmh... Could you try in IE as well please?

Comment: sorry, I don't have IE installed